# MySQL Join and group by on same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table with multiple dates, brands and markets

```
Date       | brand       | Market   |  CONV   | PgmGRPs     | 
-----------|-------------|----------|---------|-------------|
2020-01-01 | ABC         | MTL      | conv.   | 80          | 
2020-01-01 | ABC         | MTL      | Spec.   | 20          |
2020-01-01 | ABC         | TO       | conv.   | 70          |
2020-01-01 | ABC         | TO       | Spec.   | 40          |
2020-01-02 | DEF         | TO       | conv.   | 80          |
2020-01-02 | DEF         | TO       | Spec.   | 20          |
...
```

What I try to get is

```
 Date      |brand | Market |Conv. PgmGRPs |Spec. PgmGRPs |Total PgmGRPs |Conv. Ratio | Spec. Ratio|
-----------|------|--------|--------------|--------------|--------------|------------|------------|
2020-01-01 | ABC  | MTL    | 80           | 20           | 100          | 0.80       | 0.20       |
2020-01-01 | ABC  | TO     | 70           | 40           | 110          | 0.64       | 0.36       |
2020-01-02 | DEF  | TO     | 80           | 20           | 100          | 0.80       | 0.20       |
...
```

I tried the following but it didn't work

```
SELECT
a.`Brand`,
a.`PgmGRPs` as 'Conv. PgmGRPs',
b.`PgmGRPs` as 'Spec. PgmGRPs',
a.`PgmGRPs` + b.`PgmGRPs` AS 'Total PgmGRPs',
ROUND(a.`PgmGRPs`/ (a.`PgmGRPs` + b.`PgmGRPs`),2) as 'Conv. Ratio',
ROUND(b.`PgmGRPs`/ (a.`PgmGRPs` + b.`PgmGRPs`),2) as 'Spec. Ratio'

FROM 
(SELECT
`Brand`,
IF ( `CONV` = 'Conv.', SUM(`PgmGRPs`), 0)
 AS 'PgmGRPs'
FROM transform_data_1
GROUP BY `Brand`, `CONV`
) a

LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT
`Brand`,
`CONV`,
SUM(`PgmGRPs`) as 'PgmGRPs'
FROM transform_data_1
WHERE `CONV` = 'Spec.'
GROUP BY `Brand`, `CONV`
) b
ON a.`Brand` = b.`Brand`
```

Here is what I get but I can't figure out how to get the date, brand, market and remove the second line.

```
    |brand | Market |Conv. PgmGRPs |Spec. PgmGRPs |Total PgmGRPs |Conv. Ratio | Spec. Ratio|
    |------|--------|--------------|--------------|--------------|------------|------------|
    | ABC  | MTL    | 80           | 20           | 100          | 0.80       | 0.20       |
    | ABC  | MTL    | 0            | 20           | 20           | 0          | 1.00       |
    ....
```

Thanks,

Comment: you should indent your code -- that makes it easier to ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
select tab.`Date`
       , tab.brand
       , tab.market
       , Conv_PgmGRPs
       , Spec_PgmGRPs 
       , Total_PgmGRPs
       , ROUND(Conv_PgmGRPs / (Conv_PgmGRPs + Spec_PgmGRPs),2) as 'Conv. Ratio'
       , ROUND(Spec_PgmGRPs / (Conv_PgmGRPs + Spec_PgmGRPs),2) as 'Spec. Ratio'
from (select `Date`
       , brand
       , Market
       , (select sum(PgmGRPs)  
          from transform_data_1 t1 
          where t.`Date` = t1.`Date`
          and  t.brand = t1.brand
          and t.Market = t1.Market
          and t1.CONV = 'conv.') Conv_PgmGRPs
       , (select sum(PgmGRPs)  
          from transform_data_1 t1 
          where t.`Date` = t1.`Date`
          and  t.brand = t1.brand
          and t.Market = t1.Market
          and t1.CONV = 'Spec.') Spec_PgmGRPs
       , sum(PgmGRPs) Total_PgmGRPs
from transform_data_1 t
group by `Date`
       , brand
       , Market) tab
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e1c3cea086835a06795823e788007f9f)

The result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @nicolas here is the solution with the date column you requested. Hope it is ok. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting double lines is that the first query,

```
SELECT
`Brand`,
IF ( `CONV` = 'Conv.', SUM(`PgmGRPs`), 0)
 AS 'PgmGRPs'
FROM transform_data_1
GROUP BY `Brand`, `CONV`
```

is returning both lines, and you are doing a LEFT OUTER join which will always include every line from the first query.

Instead you should do what you did for the second query and have a WHERE clause to only get the `Conv` row in the first query.  Then do an INNER JOIN

```
SELECT
a.`Brand`,
a.`PgmGRPs` as 'Conv. PgmGRPs',
b.`PgmGRPs` as 'Spec. PgmGRPs',
a.`PgmGRPs` + b.`PgmGRPs` AS 'Total PgmGRPs',
ROUND(a.`PgmGRPs`/ (a.`PgmGRPs` + b.`PgmGRPs`),2) as 'Conv. Ratio',
ROUND(b.`PgmGRPs`/ (a.`PgmGRPs` + b.`PgmGRPs`),2) as 'Spec. Ratio'

FROM 
(SELECT
`Brand`,
SUM(`PgmGRPs`) AS 'PgmGRPs'
FROM transform_data_1
WHERE `CONV` = 'Conv.'
GROUP BY `Brand`
) a

INNER JOIN 
(SELECT
`Brand`,
`CONV`,
SUM(`PgmGRPs`) as 'PgmGRPs'
FROM transform_data_1
WHERE `CONV` = 'Spec.'
GROUP BY `Brand`, `CONV`
) b
ON a.`Brand` = b.`Brand`
```

This also allowed us to remove the `CONV` field from the group by, and we don't need to test for it in the select.

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation and no subqueries:

```
SELECT a.`Brand`, 
       SUM(`CONV` = 'Conv.') as ConvPgmGRPs,
       SUM(`CONV` = 'Spec.') as as SpecPgmGRPs,
       (SUM(`CONV` = 'Conv.') + SUM(`CONV` = 'Spec.')) AS 'Total PgmGRPs',
       ROUND(SUM(`CONV` = 'Conv.')/ (SUM(`CONV` = 'Conv.') + SUM(`CONV` = 'Spec.')),2) as ConvRatio,
       ROUND(SUM(`CONV` = 'Conv.')/ (SUM(`CONV` = 'Conv.') + SUM(`CONV` = 'Spec.')),2) as SpecRatio
FROM transform_data_1
GROUP BY `Brand`
```

Answer (score 0):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select date, brand, market,
  `Conv. PgmGRPs`, `Spec. PgmGRPs`, 
  `Conv. PgmGRPs` + `Spec. PgmGRPs` `Total PgmGRPs`,
  round(`Conv. PgmGRPs` / (`Conv. PgmGRPs` + `Spec. PgmGRPs`), 2)  `Conv. Ratio`,
  round(`Spec. PgmGRPs` / (`Conv. PgmGRPs` + `Spec. PgmGRPs`), 2)  `Spec. Ratio`
from (
  select date, brand, market, 
    sum(case when conv = 'conv.' then PgmGRPS end) `Conv. PgmGRPs`, 
    sum(case when conv = 'Spec.' then PgmGRPS end) `Spec. PgmGRPs`  
  from transform_data_1
  group by date, brand, market
) t
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mkC2r2Lc1UWGEop27pWMrH/0).
Results:

```
| date       | brand | market | Conv. PgmGRPs | Spec. PgmGRPs | Total PgmGRPs | Conv. Ratio | Spec. Ratio |
| -----------| ----- | ------ | ------------- | ------------- | ------------- | ----------- | ----------- |
| 2020-01-01 | ABC   | MTL    | 80            | 20            | 100           | 0.8         | 0.2         |
| 2020-01-01 | ABC   | TO     | 70            | 40            | 110           | 0.64        | 0.36        |
| 2020-01-02 | DEF   | TO     | 80            | 20            | 100           | 0.8         | 0.2         |
```

Answer (score 0):

When the the query that you are trying to develop gets too complex, the easier would be to use a staging table. You should use a crosstab/pivot table function to create the crosstab table that you are trying to create.

Step 1. Create a staging table that is a crosstab table without any calculations/ratios.
Step 2. Run sql statement to calculate totals and ratios.

Above is similar to the query that @forpas wrote above.